# Using Javascript for button and timed alert

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a button with a timer to an alert. User clicks button, two seconds later an alert pops up.

My code is resulting in the alert appearing on page load, and then again two seconds later, regardless of button click.

```
var timer = setTimeout('timeUp()', 2000)

function timeUp() {
  alert("Time's Up!");
}

document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener('click', timeUp());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function timeUp() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Time's Up!");
  }, 2000);
}

document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener('click', timeUp);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
function timeUp() {
    var timer = setTimeout('alert("Time\'s Up!")', 2000);
}

document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener('click', timeUp);
```

Comment: Why pass a string and not a function to `setTimeout`? Evaluating strings seams a bit error-prone :/

Answer (score 0):

***[UPDATED]***

I made you an example code pen :).

Simply a case of re factoring your original code a little. Take a look:

```
    function timeUp() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        return alert("hi");
      }, 2000);
    }

    document
        .getElementById("startGame")
        .addEventListener('click', timeUp);
```

Here is the link to the full codepen example.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/jamesrweb/pen/MaLVyL)